# freebsd 11 /usr/ports/emulators/ missing

Tags: freebsd, emulation

I am trying to install Linux Compatability on my FreeBSD 11.0-RELEASE-p9 #0.

I followed the guide at [freebsd docs](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/linuxemu-lbc-install.html).

In particular, I *successfully* installed `pkg install emulators/linux_base-c6`.

However, the directory `/usr/ports/emulators/linux_base-c6` simply doesn't exist on my system (and neither does the parent directory `emulators`).

Where is my emulator?  (I see many troubleshooting things online that refer to the existence of this directory.  I'm having trouble troubleshooting without it!)

Comment: Richard Smith said: `/usr/ports` is where the [ports collection](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/ports-using.html) lives. See [this link](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/ports-overview.html) for the difference between `pkg` and ports. I expect the Linux libraries are under `/compat/linux/` and started using `linux_enable="YES"`

Comment: I do have a `/compat/linux` with linux dependencies in it.  Are the contents of `/compat/linux` the equivalent of what is found under `emulators/linux_base-c6` on other computers?

Answer (score 3):

> the directory […] simply doesn't exist on my system

You have not *installed the ports tree*.  If you want to use ports (which can be used alongside packages, as ports simply apply the same package mechanism to packages built locally from source) then you need to install the ports tree.

Of course, if you want to continue just using the binary package that you have downloaded from a binary package repository, then you *do not* need to install the ports tree.  The ports tree *is not necessary* for the actual running of the packaged softwares.

As for where the binary package installed its files: That is a simple exercise in the use of the `pkg` command.

```
pkg query '%Fp' emulators/linux_base-c6
```

Comment: The output of the `pkg query '%Fp' emulators/linux_base-c6` is blank.